# How to set the order of fields

Tags: node.js, pino

I've setup the pino logger, but I see that the most important fields are in the end of the line. Is there a way to rearrange these fields? As I know, the `json.stringify` preserves the order of regular fields. I need i.e. level, status, msg, route, details to be in the very beginning, and time, version, requestid, etc at the very end.